# Eclipse doesn't import all Axis2 jars but project still runs on Tomcat?

Tags: eclipse, web-services, tomcat, websphere, apache-axis

When I develop an Axis2 web service on Eclipse, I noticed that Eclipse is automatically copying the classes from the lib folder of Axis2 to the lib folder of the new project. However, not all classes from the lib folder of Axis2 are being copied. Interestingly, the web service runs without any problem when deployed to Tomcat via Eclipse even if some the jars from Axis2 were not copied. Also, when I viewed the temp file of Tomcat, Tomcat seems to generate the jars for the listed modules on modules.list of the web service.

Can someone enlighten me regarding what is happening on this? Why Eclipse doesn't copy all the jars from Axis2? Why can the web service run on Tomcat even without the other jars from Axis2? What are those temp files for? When and why is it being generated?

I tried to run the same project on WebSphere and I am encountering a ClassDefNotFound exception because of the missing jars. My problem was solved when I copied all the Axis2 jars that was not copied by Eclipse to my project. But I'm not comfortable with my solution because Tomcat can run my project even without those jars. Is my solution really the right solution? Or am I missing a configuration setting?

**This is just for clarification:**

My web service is already running in Axis2. My class loading policy is set to PARENT_LAST. I know that since WebSphere has its own Axis2 configuration, the class loading policy must be set to PARENT_LAST so that WebSphere will use the Axis2 from the project itself. Aside from setting the class loading policy, I did something to make my web service run on WebSphere. I describe what I did above. My question is why such method must be taken?

Answer (score 1):

WebSphere has it's own axis2 configuration as part of its Java EE server spec for JAX-WS. Change your class loading policy to PARENT_LAST and check if that solves your problem.

Edit:
As the original post already states: WebSphere is a Java EE server depending on version it supports its the standard Java JAX-WS web services. Actually web services became part of the standard jdk.

If you use JAX-WS like mentioned in [Introduction to JAX-WS](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/jax_ws_2/) or [building web services](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/2.0/tutorial/doc/JAXWS.html) then you don't have to add any 3rd party library for getting your web services running. As soon as you use the non JDK implementation like axis2 you have to package it with your application.

IBM didn't just pack the axis2 into their WAS/JDK, they modified it. I'm not sure what Tomcat delivers, however as long as you use JAX-WS it shouldn't matter. With JAX-WS you don't have any direct import of the `org.apache.axis` packages. If you use these imports you have to supply the libraries and make sure that yours are loaded.

Comment: I already told him that (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8502240/module-is-not-valid-when-deploying-an-axis2-web-service-on-websphere), but he wouldn't hear...

Comment: @AndreasVeithen: I know that WebSphere has its own configuration. By the time I asked the question that you answered, my class loading policy is already set to PARENT_LAST. That is why I posted my questions because even though my class loading policy is already set to PARENT_LAST, my web service is still not working. Anyway, my webservice is already working and your solution is not the solution to my problem. I posted my answer on my own question. Maybe you haven't checked it back yet. And my current question is not how to solve it.

Comment: @Udo Held: I appreciate your response but my question is not how to solve it. I was already able to run my web service on Axis2. My approach was indicated on my post. My question is why such approach is needed to make an Axis2 web service run on WebSphere. And it is not about the class loading policy.

Comment: Updated the post. Use JAX-WS and you can throw your libs out.

Comment: @Udo Held: Thank you! That is why I'm a bit confused here because I know the missing jars are required for the web service to run. But even though that is the case, Tomcat has no problem it. :/ I haven't tried developing with JAX-WS yet but I will surely study it. Thanks for the link that you have given! But still our web service is already using Axis2 so I have to make it run while also knowing how things work on the server.

Comment: @Arci: Your comments show that you didn't follow the recommended procedure to set up Axis2 in WebSphere, in contrast to what you claimed in the other question. In fact, in addition to configuring the Web module class loader with parent last, you also need to change the policy for the class loaders created by Axis2. If you don't do this, then there is still a workaround which indeed involves adding things to WEB-INF/lib. Apparently you are in that latter case, but since you failed twice to provide accurate information, we won't be able to help you.

Comment: @AndreasVeithen: I updated my other question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8502240/module-is-not-valid-when-deploying-an-axis2-web-service-on-websphere) to include the steps I've done + some version details. I hope you could check it. Also, the policy for the class loaders created by Axis2 can be changed at axis2.xml right? I already set 
EnableChildFirstClassLoading" but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: @AndreasVeithen: My project is already running in WebSphere. Thanks! I apologize for not noticing my mistake. I updated my other question again to include my mistake. And I already marked your answer as the correct answer. :D Thanks again!